# List of Class<? extends Foo> incompatible types

Tags: java, generics, incompatibletypeerror

I'm working on this piece of code:

```
List<Class<? extends Foo>> models = new ArrayList<>();
    if (bar == 0)
        models = getRandomBlas(); // returns List<Bla>
    else 
        models = getRandomBlubs(); // returns List<Blub>
```

with:

```
public class Bla extends Foo { ... }
public class Blub extneds Foo { ... }
```

But I'm getting an `Incompatible types: Found: 'java.util.List<Bla>', required: 'java.util.List<java.lang.Class<? extends Foo>'`

Has anyone got an idea? To my knowledge, this is how the `? extends` should work...

Comment: `List<? extends Foo>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. That is how [`? extends`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) works, but your list wants [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) objects.

- `List<Class<? extends Foo>>` can contain `Class` objects that represent subtypes of `Foo` (`Foo.class`, `Bla.class`, `Blub.class`).
- `List<? extends Foo>` can contain objects that are subtypes of `Foo`.

You want the second version.

Comment: thanks alot. as a python developer, types are still somwhat unfamiliar to me ;)